# How to help myself adding a koma footer?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, learning

I want to add a footer in my koma letter.

I open the [0]manual and search `Ctrl + f` `footer`.

I got 267 results for footer.

Isn't there a better way to add a footer to my document?

[0] https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jqueralt said you probably want to use `scrlayer-scrpage`, but depending on your needs you might not even need that. How can you find this out on your own? As you noticed, using `Strg + f` is not the most effective way to find something in a comprehensive manual. Instead, it's always best to start by looking into the table of contents:

The table of contents contains (an introduction, some appendices and) two main parts: "KOMA-Script for Authors" and "KOMA-Script for Advanced Users and Experts". Since you are looking for footers which is not a perticularly advanced concept, you have to look at the first part.

Here you probably find two interesting sections:

First there is the section "4. Letters with the `scrlttr2` Class or the `scrletter` Package". As the name suggests, it contains everything which is specific to letters. The table of Contents especially shows that it contains subsections like "4.10.8 Letterhead Page Footer" or "4.13 Headers and Footers with the Default Page Style".

If you have more complicated needs, the section "5. Headers and Footers with `scrlayer-scrpage`" should catch your eye. (It is also referenced from 4.13. It tells you everything about how to setup headers and footers using that package. ("5.4. Using Predefined Page Styles" is probably the most interesting one if you don't have complicated needs) (As a general rule, subsections x.1-x.3 are basically the same in all chapters and enough to read one of them. They document how to generally set options and settings in all KOMA classes/packages)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is calling the `scrlayer-scrpage` package.

You can put text in 3 points of header or footer: the outer part of the page, with `\ohead` or `\ofoot`, the central part, with `\chead` or `\cfoot` and the inner part of the page, with `\ihead` or `\ifoot`.

Look at the MWE and try to comment and uncomment lines and put text inside the brackets:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext} % dummy text

%---------- headers and footers --------------
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
%-------- header
\ihead{}            % empty header
\chead{}            % empty header
\ohead{}            % empty header
%-------- footer
\ifoot{Some text}   % inner footer with a fixed text
\cfoot{\headmark}   % central footer with heading on level 1 (section)
\ofoot{\pagemark}   % outer footer with the page number

\begin{document}
 \blinddocument
\end{document}
```